# Can I use the apache httpclient in android to connect with a MS .net web API service

Tags: android, asp.net-web-api

Can I use the Apache (org.apache.http.client.HttpClient) library within Android to connect with a Microsoft WebAPI service?

Is there a better library set to use?

Is there sample code for this anywhere?

Comment: Is Microsoft WebAPI service listening using HTTP protocol - did you try it?

Comment: I don't know, I"m sorry.  I have built a very basic standard .net WEB API service.  I can read easily enough from the service, but I am unsure how to post new entities etc - so before I start I want to check it is normal practice to use the apache libray or some other library?

Comment: If you are using java and connecting to HTTP then this is a good choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using java and connecting to HTTP then this is a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes.  I have done a read and insert using this library.  If anyone wants the code, yell out